# Package Won't Install

Tags: packages, miktex

I'm using TexMakerX as part of Protext on Windows 7. I am trying to use the `resume` package, which I haven't used before so I downloaded an example TeX file. As I expected when I tried to use it, I asked me if I wanted to install the `resume` package.

[image: Screenshot]

I clicked the install button, but nothing seemed to happen. I checked that the path was correct, and have successfully installed packages before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you encounter similar problems if you run MikTeX's own Package Manager program to install the package in question? If so, there may be something amiss with your MikTeX installation.

Comment: I can't find the package resume, so I guess you are using `\documentclass{res}` (if that is wrong, could you please show the line of code you are using?). The [`res` CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/res) says the package is not available from MiKTeX.

Comment: I just tried to use `res.cls` and it was installed without problem from my local repository. What happens when you compile again your test file?

Comment: Have you tried to install the package manually, using the MiKTeX package manager? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156440/trying-to-add-the-cbgreek-package-causes-texstudio-and-or-miktex-to-hang-large

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer, because comments cannot contain images.
You say you checked the path to be correct, but could you also check if it works if you install the package from a remote repository as shown in the image?

[image: MiKTeX package repository]

Comment: In this case, you might consider marking the answer "community wiki" ;)

Comment: Changed it to community wiki. Had never done that before...